# Unable to run any Appium test on real Android device. Bad parameters: BadParametersError: Parameters were incorrect

Tags: java, android, selenium-webdriver, appium

I am trying to run an Appium test on a real android device. The java class was generated using Appium Inspector:

```
package some.package;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class somename{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("appium-version", "1.5.3");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "6.0.1");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "d61462ac");
        capabilities.setCapability("app", "/Users/myuser/Documents/projects/testapplication/build/outputs/apk/myapp-debug.apk");
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.package");
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.myapp.LaunchApp");
        WebDriver wd = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        wd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        wd.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[1]")).click();
        wd.close();
    }
}
```

The Appium log is this one (starting Appium and launching the test script):

```
 Launching Appium with command: 
'/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node' appium/build/lib/main.js --address "127.0.0.1" --pre-launch --debug-log-spacing --automation-name "Appium" --platform-name "Android" --platform-version "6.0.1" --app "/Users/myuser/Documents/projects/testapplication/build/outputs/apk/myapp-debug.apk" --dont-stop-app-on-reset --device-name "e20123ee"

[Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.5.3

[Appium] Non-default server args:

[Appium]   address: '127.0.0.1'

[Appium]   launch: true
[Appium]   debugLogSpacing: true
[Appium]   platformName: 'Android'
[Appium]   platformVersion: '6.0.1'
[Appium]   automationName: 'Appium'
[Appium]   deviceName: 'd61462ac'
[Appium]   app: '/Users/myuser/Documents/projects/testapplication/build/outputs/apk/myapp-debug.apk'
[Appium]   dontStopAppOnReset: true
[Appium] Deprecated server args:
[Appium]   --platform-name => --default-capabilities '{"platformName":"Android"}'
[Appium]   --platform-version => --default-capabilities '{"platformVersion":"6.0.1"}'
[Appium]   --automation-name => --default-capabilities '{"automationName":"Appium"}'
[Appium]   --device-name => --default-capabilities '{"deviceName":"d61462ac"}'
[Appium]   --app => --default-capabilities '{"app":"/Users/myuser/Documents/projects/testapplication/build/outputs/apk/myapp-debug.apk"}'
[Appium]   --dont-stop-app-on-reset => --default-capabilities '{"dontStopAppOnReset":true}'
[Appium] Default capabilities, which will be added to each request unless overridden by desired capabilities:
[Appium]   platformName: 'Android'
[Appium]   platformVersion: '6.0.1'
[Appium]   automationName: 'Appium'
[Appium]   deviceName: 'd61462ac'
[Appium]   app: '/Users/myuser/Documents/projects/testapplication/build/outputs/apk/myapp-debug.apk'
[Appium]   dontStopAppOnReset: true

[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 127.0.0.1:4723

[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

[MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.getStatus() with args: []

[MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.getStatus() result: {"build":{"version":"1.5.3"...

[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 17 ms - 83 

[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"/Users/myuser/Documents/projects/testapplication/build/outputs/apk/myapp-debug.apk","appPackage":"com.package","appActivity":"com.myapp.LaunchApp","appium-version":"v1.5.3","platformVersion":"6.0.1","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"d61462ac"},"requiredCapabilities":{},"capabilities":{"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"/Users/myuser/Documents/projects/testapplication/build/outputs/apk/myapp-debug.apk","appPackage":"com.package","appActivity":"com.myapp.LaunchApp","appium-version":"v1.5.3","platformVersion":"6.0.1","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"d61462ac"},"requiredCapabilities":{}},"alwaysMatch":{"app":"/Users/myuser/Documents/projects/testapplication/build/outputs/apk/myapp-debug.apk","appPackage":"com.package","appActivity":"com.myapp.LaunchApp","appium-version":"v1.5.3","platformVersion":"6.0.1","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"d61462ac"},"firs

[debug] [MJSONWP] Bad parameters: BadParametersError: Parameters were incorrect. We wanted {"required":["desiredCapabilities"],"optional":["requiredCapabilities","sessionId","id"]} and you sent ["desiredCapabilities","requiredCapabilities","capabilities","alwaysMatch","firstMatch"]
```

I am using Eclipse 4.6.3 on OSX 10.11.6, Appium 1.5.3, java-client-5.0.0-BETA5.jar and selenium-server-standalone-3.3.1.jar

Using Appium I can start the app. but I can't do that from Eclipse.

Can someone help me understand what I misconfigured?

Comment: Everything looks good for me... Can you check it run without the "Appium-version" capability

Comment: I just tried it and I got the same result. I tried a bunch of combinations of commented setCapability lines, and I was unable to get a different result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check if you have all the libraries installed. Please take a look at the following picture and let us know if you have all the libraries. Everything should work after this.

```
GSON-x.x.x.jar
Java-client-x.x.x-javadoc.jar
Java-client-x.x.x-sources.jar
java-client-x.x.x.jar
selenium-java-x.x.x.zip
selenium-server-standalone-x.x.x.jar
```

Comment: Adding all these libraries fixed my issue. For the record, I am now using:
- gson-2.8.0.jar
- java-client-5.0.0-BETA8-javadoc.jar
- java-client-5.0.0-BETA8-sources.jar (Replacing BETA5)
- java-client-5.0.0-BETA8.jar
- selenium-java-3.3.0.zip
- selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar (replacing 3.3.1)

Comment: Sorry for not posting sooner - this actually fixed my issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below altered capability...

```
capabilities.setCapability("app", "myapp-debug.apk");
```

Make sure, that apk is installed in your Android device.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add selenium standalone server 2.5. Not 3.3.1 in your project.

BETA4 of java client only works with Selenium prior to version 3.2.

BETA5 supports 3.2+